# How is it possible that I get ClassNotFound exception while the IDE finds the class?

Tags: java

I added this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then my controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
public String test() {
    Keycloak kc = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl("http://localhost:8180/auth")
            .realm("test-realm")
            .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
            .clientId("admin-cli")
            .username("admin")
            .password("admin")
            .build();

    String str = "Test controller ran";
    return str;
}
```

The IDE does not say anything about KeycloakBuilder missing. I can open the class and see it's body but when I call the controller:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:144) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.keycloak.controller.RealmController.test(RealmController.java:73) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
```

Can't really fix a problem if there is no problem... Or can I?

Comment: Did you export it as a JAR?

Comment: I did not export anything.

Comment: How do you run the project?

Comment: You didn't add the jar file to the classpath when you ran the program.

Comment: I run it from eclipse. I added the dependency to the pom.xml.

Comment: Have you tried `mvn clean package`, sometimes the maven indices do not import new dependencies correctly

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, the IDE does not refresh the changes in the pom. You can do the following steps:

1. Run in the command line *mvn clean eclipse:eclipse*
2. Select the entire project in Eclipse and press F5